# GoogleMaps API watchPosition

Tags: google-maps

I have the code:

```
var watchID;
        var geoLoc;

        var geoService = navigator.geolocation;
        if (geoService) {
            geoService.getCurrentPosition(showCurrentLocation,errorHandler,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
        } else {
            alert("Your Browser does not support GeoLocation.");
        }

        function showCurrentLocation(position){
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

            //Google Map options
            var myOptions = {zoom: 16,
                             center: latLng,
                             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var usermarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng, map: map, title: "You are here!"});

            map.setCenter(latLng);
            usermarker.setPosition(latLng);
            getLocationUpdate(usermarker, latLng)
        }

        function errorHandler(error){
              alert("Error while retrieving current position. Error code: " + error.code + ",Message: " + error.message);
        }

        function getLocationUpdate(usermarker, latLng){
           if(navigator.geolocation){
              var options = {timeout:60000};
              geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
              watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocation, 
                                             errorHandler,
                                             options);
           }else{
              alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
           }
        }

        function showLocation(position){
            op = document.getElementById("output");
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            op.innerHTML = "Latitude : " + latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + longitude;
        }
```

which sets up the map and gets my current location. I am trying to get the map to center and the marker to move. getLocationUpdate currently fires the watchLocation but I have no idea how to update the marker and the map center.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));`

it centers the "moving map"...

Answer (score 0):

You setting the position to the marker in a wrong way, try:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng)
```

and you can update the position of the marker with:

```
newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
marker.setPosition(newLatlng);
```

called inside showLocation(position)

Hope it helps...